# Cannot build scipy from source

Tags: python, build, scipy

I am following the steps specified [here](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/dev/dev_quickstart.html) under the *pip+venv* tab. I was able to create the virtual environment and install all the python level dependencies, but then when I navigate into `/wherever/I/cloned/scipy` and run `python dev.py build` I get `meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Cython compiler 'cython' cannot compile programs`. If I look into the log it says

```
Compiler stderr:
...
  File "/home/me/.venvs/scipy-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pythran/optimizations/pattern_transform.py", line 346, in <module>
    getattr(PatternTransform, attr_name) + (known_pattern,))
AttributeError: type object 'PatternTransform' has no attribute 'typePatterns'. Did you mean: 'CallPatterns'?
```

How can I fix this and build scipy?

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is related to the Pythran package, which is for optimizing the compiler for better efficiency. Try pip uninstall pythran and building scipy and installing pythran, if needed later.